# What is PSA short for?

Tags: abbreviations

I saw [an article](https://penandblot.medium.com/dear-nice-guys-these-3-behaviours-make-us-incredibly-uncomfortable-54130126cff4) with the following passage.

> This is a **PSA** for all the ‘nice guys’ out there — please kindly f--k off.

While I understand by the context that it's some kind of warning or heads-up, I haven't found much explanation when I searched for that abbreviation. I get that it's nothing with prostates.

Comment: Almost certainly [Public Service Announcement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_service_announcement). The term is being used sarcastically.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Oh, I didn't think of that. I'm used to *PA* for that meaning. I've never seen *P**S**A* and there are no suggested references to that on Google. Surprising...

Comment: @MichaelHarveyMight be an idea to repost your comment as an answer to be accepted.